# FFMPEG color to transparencyq

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a mp4 video with a completely uniform pink color to a mov file seuch that the pink color is transparent.

I have run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "chromakey=0xf25b98:0.01:0" -c copy -c:v png output.mov
```

I confirmed that #f25b98 is the color I am replacing. This makes absolutely nothing transparent. When I try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "chromakey=0xf25b98:0.02:0" -c copy -c:v png output.mov
```

I get some weird transparent dots in my pink but still nothing is changed (see attached screenshot from video).

Why would ffmpeg exhibit this behavior?

[image: output image]

Comment: Hi Andrew :). Video streams in MP4s typically store color in YUV encoding, not RGB. The chromakey filter will convert the video to RGB encoding but as there are multiple YUV <-> RGB transformation mappings, it may not convert to the RGB value you're expecting. Quickest way forward is to export a frame or two as PNG and then use a color picker to identify the color.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that it is not possible to use FFMPEG to remove a keyframe from an already compressed video stream because the compression introduces bleed which makes for an imprecise transparency.